# Notification not being called after app is closed and reopened with the notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

When using the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static AtomicInteger notificationId = new AtomicInteger(0);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif )
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle("Request Received")
            .setContentText("new Notif")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE));
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId.incrementAndGet(), mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

The following user behavior creates an inconsistent approach to notifications:

1. User opens the application, a new notification appears.
2. User closes the application.
3. User clicks the notification.
4. A new notification is created and the app is opened.
5. User clicks the notification (while the app is opened, if the app is closed the notification behaves as expected).
6. Nothing happens.  Following log message is visible: 02-28 14:09:15.966 840-2273/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=app.myapplication/.MainActivity} from uid 10093 from pid -1 on display 0
   02-28 14:09:15.966 840-2273/? W/ActivityManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=app.myapplication/.MainActivity }, which doesn't make sense as the Activity is currently open.

Is there something in my code that is causing this behavior?
Is this behavior expected?

Furthermore, I would like to mention the following use case gives the expected notification behavior:

1. User opens the application, a new notification appears.
2. User clicks the notification.
3. A new notification is created and the MainActivity is opened. -> go to step 2.

This behavior is evident on Android 5 and 6, but has not been tested on Android 7.

Comment: What value is defined for your MainActivity `android:launchMode` in Manifest?

Comment: I don't define it, as such it is "standard" I believe.  Based on the log message listed above, it believes it is instantiating a new task.

Comment: [It is not](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to appear based on: "When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in."  With regards to "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK".  This caused "the current task" to be brought to the screen when it was already active.

Answer (score 0):

**move below code to onResume() method**

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif )
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle("Request Received")
            .setContentText("new Notif")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE));
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId.incrementAndGet(), mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I would expect the use case to be as such for the first case I described:

1.  User opens the application, a new notification appears.
2.  User closes the application.
3.  User clicks the notification.
4.  A new notification is created and the app is opened.
5.  User clicks the notification (while the app is opened, if the app is closed the notification behaves as expected).
6.  A new notification is created and the activity is relaunched.

However, if you read my question, this is not what occurs.